# How can I make the "None" word in the pagination disappear?

Tags: python, html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have these codes below that show the pagination (changing page button) but somehow, the right_current = 2 is causing the button to show "None" in the middle:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
         <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            {% for page_num in many_posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
                {% if many_posts.page==page_num %}
                    <li class='page-item disabled'>
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('core.index', page=page_num)}}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class='page-item'>
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('core.index', page=page_num)}}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
          </ul>
     </nav>
```

**Image of the pagination button:**

[image]

I would like to ask if is there could be any way I hide the word "None" and custom that middle button with CSS or Bootstrap...

I'm a beginner and I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put one if statement to check if there is a page_num. If not just put "..."

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
         <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            {% for page_num in many_posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
              {% if page_num %}
                  {% if many_posts.page==page_num %}
                      <li class='page-item disabled'>
                      <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('core.index', page=page_num)}}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                      </li>
                  {% else %}
                      <li class='page-item'>
                      <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('core.index', page=page_num)}}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                      </li>
                  {% endif %}
               {% else %}
                 ...
               {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
          </ul>
     </nav>
```

Comment: Hi -- quick one on code formatting. Use three backticks when formatting multi-line blocks.

Comment: Hi @roodyCool, thank you so much for helping me! Your codes worked! :)